# oro commerce -Add multiple product by api

Tags: orocommerce

I am new to OroCommerce, and it is quite difficult with the lack of documentation.

I'm looking to create several products with the API, but I can't.

I can only create one product at a time with the API "api / products" (POST method), but I don't see how to create several.

Have you ever realized this?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create multiple products using the [Batch API](https://doc.oroinc.com/api/batch-api/) that is available for products since OroCommerce 4.1.3.

See the back-office [API Sandbox](https://doc.oroinc.com/api/sandbox/) for more details and an example.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I will migrate to version 4.1.3.